# How do i satisfy business requirements across microservices with immediate consistenc?

Tags: microservices, eventual-consistency, data-consistency

Let’s assume I’m in the context of an admin panel for a webshop. I have a list of orders. Those orders are payed for and are ready to ship. The (admin) user would like to start making shipments based on the items ordered.

Imagine there are 2 microservices. One for orders and one for shipments. In order to create a shipment, i will send a request with a couple of items to be shipped and an order ID to the shipment service. The shipment service will then check whether the items are present in the order by querying the order service. Because i don’t want to create a shipment with items that are not present in the order.

I’d like to have immediate consistency because the shipment data will be send to a third-party application after creation. Thereby it also feels weird to allow shipments to be created if the data is not correct.

I’m also using GraphQL mutations. Which means i have to return the updated state to the user, which also makes eventual consistency a lot harder.

What is the recommended approach for these situations? Could this be a sign that these 2 microservices need to be merged? I can imagine this situation can occur multiple times.

Comment: re: "i need to check whether the provided items have actually been ordered.". It's not clear why a shipment would be created without an order, can you elaborate on that?

Comment: @Nir Alfasi Yes, i will update my question.

Comment: What if only some of the items in the order are available for shipment?